# Excel VBA cell referencing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm growing extremely frustrated with the following code:

```
Range("H" & LastRow + 1).Select
NewRow = LastRow + 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=C3R" & NewRow & "*C8R" & NewRow
```

I keep getting errors on the last line, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

All I need in the cell is: `=C6*G6`

Comment: Wouldn't G6 acutally be `C7R` instead of `C8R`?

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=C" & NewRow & "*G" & NewRow

Comment: yeah, just wrote the same in my answer 41 secs ago :p

Comment: I really just don't understand why what I wrote didn't work. It makes so much more sense to do it that way though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write row first, column second - so to get the multiplication of `C` column and `G` column on same line as active cell, write: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="=RC3*RC7"`

But couldn't you just write `ActiveCell.Formula="=C" & NewRow & "*" & "G" & NewRow`?